# Do questions about sociologists/organizational scholars like Latour, Giddens, Simon, and Weick belong on philosophy.SE?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I'm a social science PhD student and I don't read or reference pure philosophers often. However, there are a number of sociologists/organizational scholars who have written books which straddle the line between philosophy and sociology/organization studies. Some examples are:

- Giddens - The Constitution of Society
- Latour - Reassembling the Social
- Simon - Sciences of the Artificial
- Weick - A Social Psychology of Organizing

Do questions with regards to these scholars belong on philosophy.stackexchange.com? By what criteria do we judge edge-cases such as these?

Comment: Our general criteria is simply whether it touches sufficiently upon an established, known area of "philosophy"; i.e., one that virtually everyone would encounter in a standard education. "Sufficiently" has up til now been a subjective judgment from the community, and in that judgment we have been very liberal. Well-formed questions showing care and thought, even if slightly off-topic or subjective, are usually accepted with open arms here. I would say feel free to ask them here, and we'll take it case by case.

Comment: FWIW, Bruno Latour is often cited in books on the philosophy of science, as a philosopher of science.